# Blender 3.2 strange texture bug

Tags: 3d-view, gpu

Default cube, default material, eevee;
Changing the texture in any way does not seem to help.

Reinstalling, downgrading to 3.1, still unsolved.

All of my older projects look like this too

[image: The bug]

Comment: there is a bug with the latest AMD driver, are you using an AMD?

Comment: @moonboots yes, i do indeed use AMD
For a matter of fact, i updated my drivers not too long ago, so, probably that's the issue
Any ideas on how to fix that, or, if it even is possible?

Comment: go into the Render panel > Performance and click on High Quality Normals. If it doesn't fix the problem, I guess you need to come back to a previous driver

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for the help, much appreciated! That helped

Comment: @moonboots ah geez another AMD issue... I had hoped they'd have a better handle on this since joining the dev fund

Comment: @Allen Simpson this driver problem has been existed for a long time now